# Read a line in xlrd python into dataframe

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I would like to read certain rows in excel into a dataframe.

```
My code looks like this:
import xlrd 
file_loc = r'PriceSheet.xlsx'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

for i in range(7,67):
    if(sheet.cell_value(i,0)) <> "":
        for j in range(1,18):
            'Need to read the row into the dataframe here.
```

How do i read a row into dataframe?

My excel data looks like this:

[image]

Comment: load data into pandas df, then remove unwanted rows

Comment: Reading Excel data into df1, setting up df2, and copying only what you need?
You didn't mention pandas, do you explicitly mean to avoid it?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi, the excel sheet is not clean. hence have to do this approach

Comment: @lakesh then fill NaN values or drop not clean rows

Comment: ok, but index is not the first row but a mix of couple of rows.

Comment: Assuming `i`, `j` are row, col numbers, you could use (at `'Need to read the row into the dataframe here.`) `df.at[<row name>, <col name>] = sheet.cell_value(i,j)` (translating from index to name is easy).
This is very simple, why wouldn't it work for your needs?